# ospf hello not forwarded

Tags: iptables, multicast, ospf

I am trying to change the destination ip of ospf hello packet (224.0.0.5) to link local address using iptables rule (DNAT) . It does not seem to work. A similar rule for unicast packet (BGP control) has worked for me. Any idea? Both the incoming interface as well as the link local interface have joined 224.0.0.5 MC group (using smcroute). I also have a rule in mangle table to increment the ttl prerouting.